# JavaScript scope in a try block

Tags: javascript, scope

Say I'm trying to execute this JavaScript snippet. Assume the undeclared vars and methods are declared elsewhere, above, and that `something` and `somethingElse` evaluate to boolean-true.

```
try {
    if(something) {
        var magicVar = -1;
    }

    if(somethingElse) {
        magicFunction(magicVar);
    }
} catch(e) {
    doSomethingWithError(e);
}
```

My question is: what is the scope of `magicVar` and is it okay to pass it into `magicFunction` as I've done?

Comment: It seems to me like this is just a question about variable scope, not variable scope within a try block.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Javascript has function scope. That means that `magicvar` will exist from the beginning of the function it's declared in all the way to the end of that function, even if that statement doesn't ever execute. This is called **variable hoisting**. The same thing happens with functions declarations, which in turn is called **function hoisting**.

If the variable is declared in global scope, it will be visible to *everything*. This is part of the reason why global variables are considered evil in Javascript.

Your example will pass `undefined` into `magicFunction` if `something` is false, because `magicVar` hasn't been assigned to anything.

While this is technically valid Javascript, it's generally considered bad style and will not pass style checkers like jsLint. Extremely unintuitive Javascript like this will execute without any error

```
alert(a); //alerts "undefined"
var a;
```

**POP QUIZ**: What does the following code do?

```
(function() {
  x = 2;
  var x;
  alert(x);
})();
alert(x);
```

Comment: The example you gave isn't quite good because it was `undefined` anyway, because `window.a` is `undefined`

Comment: @gdoron I'm not sure I see what you're getting at. If you just try to run `alert(a)` all by itself, it will throw an error like `a is 'undefined'`.

Comment: The thing is that `a` _can_ be undefined because it undefined in outerscope. Take a look on this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/H8c4n/3/) If you remove the `var x` you still get the same result.

Comment: @gdoron I still don't understand what you're getting at. My point is that [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/6bNZp/) will run without errors, whereas [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/yJMaZ/1/) will throw an error.

Comment: Alert **two** then throw an error? (if x wasn't defined in outerscope)

Comment: I meant to things [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/H8c4n/3/). the site is angry with me : `avoid extended discussions in comments.`

Answer (score 87):

Lots of other good answers about how Javascript handles this with `var`, but I thought I'd address the `let` situation...

If a variable is defined with `let` inside the `try` block, it will NOT be in scope inside the `catch` (or `finally`) block(s).  It would need to be defined in the enclosing block.

For example, in the following code block, the console output will be "Outside":

```
let xyz = "Outside";

try {
    let xyz = "Inside";

    throw new Error("Blah");
} catch (err) {
    console.log(xyz);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

- In javascript only functions create a new context -closure.
- Every definition of a variable is really a declaration of the variable at the top of its scope and an assignment at the place where the definition is.

**var**

- *function-scoped*
- **hoist to the top of its function**
- redeclarations of the same name in the same scope are no-ops

You may want to read [**MDN scope cheat sheet**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet)

Due to `hoisting` You can even do things like this:

```
function bar() {
    var x = "outer";

    function foo() {
        alert(x); // {undefined} Doesn't refer to the outerscope x
        // Due the the var hoising next:        
        x = 'inner';
        var x;
        alert(x); // inner

    }
    foo();
}

bar();​

bar();​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/H8c4n/2/)

So the `foo` function is converted to something like this:

```
function foo() {
    var x;
    alert(x); // {undefined} Doesn't refer to the outerscope x
    // Due the the var hoising next:        
    x = 'inner';
    alert(x); // inner
}​
```

> My question is: what is the scope of magicVar and is it okay to pass it into magicFunction as I've done?

Define *okay*..., Yes the code is valid, but it's less readable then if the variables declarations were on the top, that's all.

Comment: I'm torn! I love both yours and Peter Olson's. Have an upvote :)

Comment: @DarrenGreen. **:)** Don't feel bad. Just pick the best answer you think you got. (I don't like the Stackoverflow idea that accepted answers pops to the top {did I hear _hoisting_? :)}, it doesn't make sense that the guy which probably has the less knowledge on the question decide which answer is the best.) If it's Peter's answer I'm cool with it, I don't compete with out answers.

Comment: Your cheat sheet link is considered obsolete content. Love the big warning bars on that page -- you aren't gonna miss that! haha

Answer (score 6):

Due to javascript "hoisting" ([MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)), your variable declaration code gets translated as:

```
function yourFunction() {
  var magicVar;
  try {
      if(something) {
          magicVar = -1;
      }

      if(somethingElse) {
          magicFunction(magicVar);
      }
  } catch(e) {
      doSomethingWithError(e);
  }

} //end of your function
```

"Hoisting" moves all variables declarations to the top of the function.  So `magicVar` is available everywhere in the function, but it's undefined until you give it a value.

Your variable has function scope.

Answer (score 1):

With `var`, variables exist from the beginning of the function to the end of it, no matter where they are declared, or even if the statement is actually ever reached. They will, however, be `undefined` until they are assigned another value.

So in your case, if `something` is false but `somethingelse` is true, you will call `magicFunction` with its first argument being `undefined`.

The `let` keyword, created in Javascript 1.9 and available (as of today, May 3<sup>rd</sup> 2012, and as far as I know) only in Firefox, declares variables with the scoped semantics you're probably used to.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with variable hoisting and function hoisting, I would like to emphasis two import points.

- Identifier Defined in Catch parameter is i.e. err/e(error) , is scoped to Catch defined block.
- Function first hoisting.
  example :

  ```
      b(); // output : 3
      var b = 2;
      function b(){
       return 3;
      }
  ```