# Why do I get "Variable is used before being assigned" with var variable in a try-catch with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript...

```
// var xyz = "Outside";
try {
  var xyz = "Inside"; 
  throw new Error("Error");
} catch (err) {
  console.log(xyz);  //Variable 'xyz' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)
              ^^^
} finally {
  console.log(xyz);  //Variable 'xyz' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)
}
```

Why do I get a "Variable 'xyz' is used before being assigned. ts(2454)" message?

Comment: `var` is always function scoped.

Comment: @DanMullin It's `var`, so it's hoisted to the nearest containing function (or top level).

Comment: I would imagine that the compiler cannot tell for certain that `xyz` is assigned to in all cases that the code enters the `catch` or `finally`. So this has nothing to do with scope and everything to do with a variable that has not been assigned (and exactly what the error message is telling you)

Comment: They explain it in [OP 2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441717/javascript-scope-in-a-try-block) that snippet looks to be from.

Comment: var scope should in function.Then why Type-Script gave this Warning ? Is it a bug?

Comment: It's a warning because typescript cannot evaluate to a certainty that the variable will be set, even though reading the code it should be.  Even if you moved the var outside of the try catch, typescript should start yelling at you with this existing code that the variable is never changed and that you should use `const` instead.

Comment: See: [Definite Assignment Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)

Comment: I disagree with the close. The OP *thought* they were asking that question given the variation of code from an answer in that one, but also given the variation this is not about scope but not having a definitive assignment (they changed `let` to `var` but removed the definitive assignment).